# Display Flex Issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't manage to get something done with the flex property.
Basically, I want my logo to be centered on the left and my links on the right.
However, I can't achieve that because they won't split.

Thank you in advance if anyone knows how to solve this.

Keep in mind that my goal is to vertically align all of my items in the middle of the nav and to make it so the logo is on the left and the links on the right.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

/* NOTE: NAVBAR */

.main-navbar {
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 49, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.logo-image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.logo-image-warp {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.nav-link-warp {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
  float: right;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./data/css/master.css">
    <title>CulturesCITY</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="main-navbar">
      <div class="logo-image-warp">
        <img src="./data/ressources/final-logo.png" alt="LOGO" class="logo-image">
      </div>
      <div class="nav-link-warp">
        <a class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
        <a class="nav-link">À propos</a>
        <a class="nav-link">Faire un don</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm just curious what "centered on the left" means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can entirely remove `.logo-image-wrap` and add `align-items:center;` and `justify-content:space-between;` to `.main-navbar`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

/* NOTE: NAVBAR */

.main-navbar {
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 49, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items:center;
justify-content:space-between;
}

.logo-image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.nav-link-warp {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
  float: right;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navbar">
      <div class="logo-image-warp">
        <img src="./data/ressources/final-logo.png" alt="LOGO" class="logo-image">
      </div>
      <div class="nav-link-warp">
        <a class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
        <a class="nav-link">À propos</a>
        <a class="nav-link">Faire un don</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

For *vertical centering* use `align-items: center` and for *horizonal spacing* `justify-content: space-between`, which will put them apart as far as it can.

I've also changed the value of the `display` property to `flex` because it's more *behavior-appropriate*, and commented out the *unnecessary*:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

/* NOTE: NAVBAR */

.main-navbar {
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 49, 0.1);
  /*width: 100%; not necessary*/
  display: flex; /* modified */
  justify-content: space-between; /* added */
  align-items: center; /* added */
}

.logo-image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

/*  not necessary
.logo-image-warp {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
*/

/* instead use */

.logo-image {display: block} /* or better for images in general (img {display: block}) which removes the default bottom whitespace/margin */

.nav-link-warp {
  display: inline-flex; /* only this has the effect, with this example */
  /*align-items: center;*/
  /*justify-content: flex-end !important;*/
  /*float: right;*/
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navbar">
  <div class="logo-image-warp">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="LOGO" class="logo-image">
  </div>
  <div class="nav-link-warp">
    <a class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
    <a class="nav-link">À propos</a>
    <a class="nav-link">Faire un don</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your code with following snippet...

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

/* NOTE: NAVBAR */

.main-navbar {
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 49, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo-image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.logo-image-warp { 
  
}

.nav-link-warp {
   
  float: right;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./data/css/master.css">
    <title>CulturesCITY</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="main-navbar">
      <div class="logo-image-warp">
        <img src="./data/ressources/final-logo.png" alt="LOGO" class="logo-image">
      </div>
      <div class="nav-link-warp">
        <a class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
        <a class="nav-link">À propos</a>
        <a class="nav-link">Faire un don</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `.main-navbar` to `display: flex` instead of `display: inline-flex`. Otherwise it will be treated as an inline element, which will not, by default, span the full width of it's container.

Then you'll have to set `justify-content: space-between` on the same element. No need to set `display: inline-flex` to the individual items as well. And don't mix floats with flexbox.

```css
.main-navbar {
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 49, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo-image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.logo-image-warp { }

.nav-link-warp { }

.nav-link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
    <nav class="main-navbar">
      <div class="logo-image-warp">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" class="logo-image">
      </div>
      <div class="nav-link-warp">
        <a class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
        <a class="nav-link">À propos</a>
        <a class="nav-link">Faire un don</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS for the container:

```
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: center;
```

Then add an empty separator with flex-grow = 1 to create space in between your elements and the logo

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

/* NOTE: NAVBAR */

.main-navbar {
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 49, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: center;
}

.separator {
  order: 0;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}

.logo-image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.logo-image-warp {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.nav-link-warp {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
  float: right;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./data/css/master.css">
    <title>CulturesCITY</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="main-navbar">
      <div class="logo-image-warp">
        <img src="./data/ressources/final-logo.png" alt="LOGO" class="logo-image">
      </div>
      <div class="separator"></div>
      <div class="nav-link-warp">
        <a class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
        <a class="nav-link">À propos</a>
        <a class="nav-link">Faire un don</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified your CSS and using `flex` instead of `inline-flex`. Additional comment in the source.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}
/* NOTE: NAVBAR */

.main-navbar {
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 49, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* Vertical alignment in the middle */
}

.logo-image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.nav-link-warp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; /* Aligns flex items at the right */
  margin-left: auto; /* Pushes this class to the right side */
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-navbar">
  <div class="logo-image-warp">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50" alt="LOGO" class="logo-image">
  </div>
  <div class="nav-link-warp">
    <a class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
    <a class="nav-link">À propos</a>
    <a class="nav-link">Faire un don</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you Go , Try this code :)

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

/* NOTE: NAVBAR */

.main-navbar {
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 22px 0px rgba(50, 50, 49, 0.1);
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.logo-image {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.logo-image-warp {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  max-width: 40%;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.nav-link-warp {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end !important;
  float: right;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0px 10px;
  max-width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./data/css/master.css">
    <title>CulturesCITY</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="main-navbar">
      <div class="logo-image-warp">
        <img src="./data/ressources/final-logo.png" alt="LOGO" class="logo-image">
      </div>
      <div class="nav-link-warp">
        <a class="nav-link">Accueil</a>
        <a class="nav-link">À propos</a>
        <a class="nav-link">Faire un don</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```